# Want to split one full page to four div with same size using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

i confuse when using height: 100% and the content set to 25% 25% 25% 25% why it's not working (in my browser each div look really small and 100% not fill full page). Can anyone find my wrong here ?

My HTML Code :

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="height: 100%">
        <div class="row" style="height: 25%;">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
                .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
            .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
            .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="height: 25%;">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
            .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
            .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
            .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="height: 25%;">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
            .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
            <h1 class="h1Title">Azkaban</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
            .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="height: 50%;">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
            .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
            .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
            .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already read : [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

But i still don't understand why 100% -> 25% each div not working here?

OUTPUT :
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: My question is different, my question about why 100% not working?

Comment: height in % sometimes does not work as intented. Use vh which translates into viewport height for getting desired result

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your output?

Comment: CSS 101: height in percent only works if the parent element has an explicit height set.

Comment: Updated Question, i add parent div with 100% not working too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.container-fluid {
   height: 100vh;
}

.row .col-xs-4.col-md-4 {
  height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="height:25vh;">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
      .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" style="height:25vh;">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
      .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" style="height:25vh;">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
      .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      <h1 class="h1Title">Azkaban</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" style="height:25vh;">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
      .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Michael, please try now.

Comment: It works. but i want to ask, Is the responsive still work?

Comment: @Michael, hopefully it should work as we are not updating any `width` values.

Comment: Ok, thank you for help me. I mark your answer as correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Using `%`**

```css
html,
body,
.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  height: 25%;
}

.row > div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
      .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
      .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
      .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      <h1 class="h1Title">Azkaban</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
      .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using `vh`**

```css
.row {
  height: 25vh;
}

.row > div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
      .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
      .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
      .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      <h1 class="h1Title">Azkaban</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:red;">
      .col-xs-9 .col-md-7
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
      .col-xs-3 .col-md-5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both the solution not working for me. the second solution make each gap of div longer but each div size still follow content

Answer (score 2):

Add this css:

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
}
```

Hope this will work but remove the height from row. However if you are using height as "VH" safari browser will not support this.

There is already fiddle for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: For image setting use this css for Safari browser: img {
border: 0;
float: left;
width: 100%;
}